How can I iterate through the days in a date picker using Selenium WebDriver
I am trying to manipulate the date picker on Omio using Selenium in Python 3.12.3. I want it to start from today, then select the next day and so on.
Unfortunately, the departure date field is read only, so using send_keys is not an option.
I have tried to locate the currently selected date and then using that find the next day, but the WebDriver just closes instead of clicking on the next day. I also thought about using the arrow keys to move to the next day but the site doesn't accept them as input for the date picker.
current_day = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[data-cy="firstSelectedDay"]')))

next_day = current_day.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following-sibling::li[@data-e2e="calendarDay" and @data-disabled-cy="false"]')

next_day.click()


Check the code below with explanation to select the current day in the daparture date picker and to select current day +1 in the return date picker:
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.omio.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on Accept all cookies button(if this pop-up doesn't appear on your screen then delete this line of code)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept all']"))).click()

# Click on Departure Date picker
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "buttonDepartureDate"))).click()

# Click on current day
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//li[@data-disabled-cy='false'])[1]"))).click()

# Click on Return Date picker
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "buttonReturnDate"))).click()

# Click on current day + 1 (if you want current day + 2, just change the value in the below XPath to [3])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//li[@data-disabled-cy='false'])[2]"))).click()
time.sleep(15)

